# Unable to set breakpoint CLR won't let me

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I'm attempting to debug some unit tests for a C# 4.0 project (vs 2012 ultimate).  I am continually encountering the following message when trying to place break points on some of the lines:

The Common Language Runtime was unable to set the breakpoint.

The project is running in Debug mode (not release), and Optimization is turned off.  The lines of code I am trying to put the breakpoint on are executable.

Example

```
var item = TourDivisionSpecCache.GetItem(divisionCode, tourYearCode, tourCode);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a condition on the breakpoint that's broken.

Comment: This happens on a large portion of the code.  If I use step-over, a lot of the lines of code get skipped and things behave unexpectedly.

Comment: I would reboot and install all service packs and updates. That is not how it is supposed to behave.

Comment: Have you been changing the date on your computer to test this code?

Comment: Rebooted, installed 2012 Update 3, still same problem, same lines of code.  No I have not touched my clock.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to debug an already running process or a remote debug by any chance ? There seems to be an issue where you can no longer correctly debug an 4.0 application if 4.5 is installed. This seems to be as a result of the 4.5 assemblies getting placed in the same directory as the original 4.0. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251082/windbg-expects-different-version-of-mscordacwks-dll) for a very similar issue I had. The only solution I found was to update the base application to 4.5